# How do I print the value of 'i' at a certain point in a cycle?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int largestChain = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        if(chain(i) > largestChain) {
            largestChain = chain(i);  // Here, how do I print the final value
                                      // of 'i' that respects the rule chain(i)?
        }
    }
    System.out.print(largestChain);
}
```

For example, if `i = 13`, `chain(i) = 10`, and the `largestChain` up to 13 (from 1) is 10. Now let's suppose that we have a cycle, from 1 to 100, and the `largestChain` is still 10, of the same `i = 13`. How do I print that `i`, when the cycle must complete its task (and to go to 100)?

Comment: Assign `i` to some local variable and keep it!

Comment: It still doesn't work. It goes up to the maximum value of i, which is 999999.

Comment: Check the code I posted.

Comment: Here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a1befa1e1d93c6253f0f

Answer (score 2):

May be this is what you want :

```
public static void main(String[]args){

    int largestChain = 0;
    int largestIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 1000000; ++i){
        if(chain(i) > largestChain){
            largestChain = chain(i); 
            largestIndex = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Largest chain is :"+largestChain);
    System.out.print("Largest chain index is :"+largestIndex);
}
```

Comment: It still prints the largest value of i (999999) and it doesn't print the value of i when chain(i) has reached the max value..

Comment: Can you post the entire code which you have tried, with sample data?

Comment: I saw the code, the output is as expected! Any specific case you want to point out?

Comment: I need to find the number that produces the longest chain (which is 264722054 - !to clarify - this is the longest chain, not the number i). It's one of those 'i's in the cycle, but I don't know how to print it. Also, I'm not interested in the result as how I'm interested in the method of finding it. Thanks for helping me. Also, for example if I just print chain(999999), the largest value of i, I don't get the same number (264722054).

Answer (score 1):

```
    int largestChain = 0;
    int index =0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 1000000; ++i){
        if(chain(i) > largestChain){
            largestChain = chain(i); //here, how do I print the final value of 'i' that respects the rule chain(i) 
            index = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(largestChain + " index  : " + index);
```